# Black tiles in rendering RAW photos with Core Image

Tags: cocoa, cgcontext, core-image

I'm trying to render a RAW image with Core Image on OS X, using 
`[render:toIOSurface:bounds:colorSpace:]`.

However, often, there are some black tiles in the result (as in the example below).

The location of the black tiles is not consistent.

The problem seems to occur more frequently on older Mac Models.

This happens both on 10.9 and 10.10 (haven't tried older versions).

Any ideas for a solution?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was?

Answer (score -1):

We ran into a similar problem when combining the output of CIRAWFilter and a lanczos filter. We reported it to Apple, but haven't heard back yet. It turns out to be such a problem as you don't really need lanczos with CIRAWFilter output and can more easily use a inputScaleFactor to downsize your output.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the time it takes to CoreImage to render the RAW image, which depends on many parameters such as the destination image format and the whole filter graph. I render to a half-precision IOSurface and experience similar issues.